# C++ Allocated Memory Problem

Tags: c++, python, memory-management, ctypes

It has been a long time since I have programmed in C++, but I recently wrote a little C++ function and am having a little bit of trouble. The function returns a struct, Result, that have some strings in it. I thought I allocated memory for the strings, but jsonResult is sometimes partially overwritten.

```
    //The structs
    struct Interp {
         int score;
         char* sentence;
         char* jsonResult;
    };

    struct Result {
         int resultCode;
         char* errorMessage;
         Interp interp;
    };
```

...

```
    //Inside the function
    Result result;

    //Store decode
    const char* jsonResult,* sentence;
    if (result.resultCode == -1)
    {
            LVInterpretation interp = port.GetInterpretation(voiceChannel, 0);

            result.interp.score = interp.Score();
            sentence = interp.InputSentence();
            jsonResult = interp.ResultData().Print(SI_FORMAT_ECMA);
    }

    //Allocate memory for strings
    result.interp.jsonResult = new char[strlen(jsonResult) + 1];
    strcpy(result.interp.jsonResult, jsonResult);

    result.interp.sentence = new char[strlen(sentence) + 1];
    strcpy(result.interp.sentence, sentence);

    result.errorMessage = new char[strlen(errorMessage) + 1];
    strcpy(result.errorMessage, errorMessage);

    return result;
```

Other info:
I am observing all of this behind the python binding that I wrote, using ctypes. Don't think that is really effecting anything though.

Comment: Using `std::string` would really save you a lot of headaches here.

Comment: You are not showing nearly enough code for us to guess where the problem might be. In particular, the code that frees the memory you have been allocating is missing from this display.

Comment: I don't really know what other code to show. This is the only code that deals with those strings. I am just wondering if I properly allocated memory for the strings. If I did, then the problem is most likely with my python binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put money on your problem being in here:

```
jsonResult = interp.ResultData().Print(SI_FORMAT_ECMA);
```

Who 'owns' the char* array returned by Print()? Maybe it's attempting to return a pointer to memory that's out of scope???

example:

```
  char* badFunction(void)
  {
     char test[100];
     strcpy(test,"This is really clever"); // oh, yeah?
     return test; // returns pointer to data that's out of scope
  }
```

One other thing. Assign null pointers to sentence, jsonResult, etc when you declare them. Otherwise you could end up strcpy()ing uninitialized data,

Comment: That sounds right to me, as jsonResult is the only one that I have been having trouble with. An outside library 'owns' it. How would I assure that the data doesn't pass out of scope?

Comment: @Veered: If Print() really returns char *, then the documentation for Print() *MUST* specify ownership semantics. The only valid (but ugly) approach is that Print() allocates the memory and requires the caller to delete[] it afterwards. If Print() has the bug I describe, you're sunk...

Comment: Ok, looks like I missed a part of the docs. The string returned by Print() is released when the object returned by ResultData() is released. So I created a memory leak, but shouldn't the string still be safe until I transfer it?

Comment: The object returned by ResultData() was passing out of scope, causing the string returned by Print() to be freed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Use `std::string`. You won't regret it.

Comment: I can't. Ctypes requires a char*.

Comment: You can provide a char* via the std::string::c_str method.

Comment: Won't I still have to allocate memory for the char*? Because memory allocation is the source of my problems.

Comment: I'm not really that familiar with Ctypes, but `std::string::c_str` actually returns `const char*`.  I think Ctypes defines some data type like `char_p` which is a `char*`.  Maybe some API functions actually don't accept `const char*`.

Comment: I would bet that using a std:string would be perfectly fine here using the .c_str method.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. What does "partially overwritten" mean? How do you know this? i.e. what is your expected output vs. what you see?
2. It's not really clear how `result.resultCode` is set to -1 (or if it is at all), and if it is set, how does the memory get allocated in `interp.InputSentence()` and `interp.ResultData().Print(SI_FORMAT_ECMA)`? I'd suggest that your problem lies there

The rest of the code should work as long as `jsonResult` and `sentence` contain valid null terminated strings.

Comment: 1. I would expect something like: '[{score : 880,word : "drum"}]', but would get '[{score : 880,worPORT CLOSED'.  Or some thing like that. 2. I set resultCode to -1 earlier, I just didn't want to show the whole function, because it is ~200 lines. And I am not sure how memory gets allocated for the interp.* functions because those are an outside library.